# Remove existing attribute from file

Tags: c#, windows

I used the `System.IO.File.SetAttributes` method to set the file attributes

what method I need to use if I want to remove a existing file attribute and keep the other attributes unmodified?

Comment: Fetch the file attributes, change the bit(s) you want to change, then write the new value.

Comment: @HarryJohnston 's comment is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the examples on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx